How to create 3D surface with different layers that each have their own colormap in matlab?
How can I create a 3D map of the glacier (bedrock + glacier surface + debris surface) with each a different colormap in Matlab? I tried several things but it does not work. Only 1 colormap is used and not a separate one for each distinct layer. How can I solve this?

close all;
clear;
clc;

% Load data
bedrock = double(geotiffread('bedrock_oct2023.tif'));
icethick = ncread(file_name, 'icethick');
h_debris = ncread(file_name, 'h_debris');

% Define grid for plotting
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size(bedrock, 2), 1:size(bedrock, 1));

% Compute initial elevations
elevation_glacier = bedrock + icethick(:, :, 1);
elevation_debris = bedrock + icethick(:, :, 1) + h_debris(:, :, 1);

% Create figure
figure('Position', [100 100 1200 800]);
ax = axes;
hold(ax, 'on');
% Define colormaps
bedrock_cmap = copper(256);
glacier_cmap = winter(256);
debris_cmap = parula(256);

% Plot initial surfaces with different colormaps manually set using CData
bedrock_alpha = double(icethick(:, :, 1) == 0); % Transparent where glacier exists

% Plot bedrock
bedrock_surf = surf(ax, X, Y, bedrock, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'FaceAlpha', 1, 'AlphaData', bedrock_alpha);
set(bedrock_surf, 'CData', bedrock, 'EdgeColor', 'none'); % Assign bedrock elevation as CData for coloring

% Plot glacier
glacier_surf = surf(ax, X, Y, elevation_glacier, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'FaceAlpha', 1);
set(glacier_surf, 'CData', elevation_glacier, 'EdgeColor', 'none'); % Assign glacier elevation as CData for coloring

% Plot debris
debris_surf = surf(ax, X, Y, elevation_debris, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'FaceAlpha', 1);
set(debris_surf, 'CData', elevation_debris, 'EdgeColor', 'none'); % Assign debris elevation as CData for coloring

% Set different color limits and colormaps
% Bedrock surface color limits
caxis([2000 4500]);
colormap(ax, bedrock_cmap);
% Freeze the colormap for bedrock so that changes to colormap do not affect it
freezeColors(bedrock_surf);

% Glacier surface color limits
caxis([2000 4500]);
colormap(ax, glacier_cmap);
freezeColors(glacier_surf);

% Debris surface color limits
caxis([2000 4500]);
colormap(ax, debris_cmap);
freezeColors(debris_surf);

% Add glacier mask
glacier_mask = double(icethick(:, :, 1) > 0); % Convert mask to double for coloring
glacier_mask_elev = bedrock + icethick(:, :, 1);
mask_surf = surf(ax, X, Y, glacier_mask_elev, 'FaceAlpha', 1, 'EdgeColor', 'w');
set(mask_surf, 'FaceColor', 'white'); % Set mask color to white directly
% Set transparency where elevation equals bedrock (no ice)
alpha_data = (glacier_mask_elev ~= bedrock);
set(mask_surf, 'AlphaData', alpha_data, 'FaceAlpha', 'interp');

% Add colorbars
cb1 = colorbar('Position', [0.92 0.1 0.02 0.2]);
colormap(cb1, bedrock_cmap);
title(cb1, 'Bedrock');
cb2 = colorbar('Position', [0.92 0.4 0.02 0.2]);
colormap(cb2, glacier_cmap);
title(cb2, 'Glacier');
cb3 = colorbar('Position', [0.92 0.7 0.02 0.2]);
colormap(cb3, debris_cmap);
title(cb3, 'Debris');

% Set axis properties
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('Elevation (m)');
set(gca, 'XDir', 'reverse', 'FontSize', 14);
title('3D View of Glacier, Debris, Bedrock, and Glacier Mask Surface');
set(gcf, 'color', 'white');

% Set view and lighting
view(45, 35);
shading interp;
camlight('left');
camlight('right');
material dull;  % Adjust material properties
lighting phong;

I have tried the code above but the plot generates only 1 colormap for all 3 layers (bedrock + glacier + debris). I want the plot to have a distinct colormap for each of the layers.

Your MATLAB version is important here. Before R2014b, there was only one colomap per figure. Starting at R2014b, each axes has it's own colormap (still, only one per axes). There is no standard MATLAB way to have more than one colormap on an axes, you will have to resort to some manual tricks. The 2 most used methods are: (1) use 2 different axes, each with their respective colormap, then surperpose them. You will have to manually link axis limits, adjust colorbar positions and Z-order of the axis to get a desired result. This works OK for 2D plots, 3D surfaces may not mix well

or (2) concatenate the colormaps, and then shift/scale the color data CData of the different plot handles to line up with the desired portions of the colormap. A good example (and a link to a Mathworks article about it) can be found in this answer. (3) Lastly, you could try some helper functions from the file exchange. freezeColors seems to handle multiple colormap per figure.
